# Change over from Mumbai international to domestic airport

Tags: india, international-travel, domestic-travel, mumbai, bom

I am arriving at Mumbai International airport at 10pm. My next flight is at 5:10am from Mumbai domestic airport to Rajkot.

I believe it is possible to stay at the international airport over night as I read some of the articles. Bu I want to know will there be inter-terminal buses from international airport to domestic airport as early as 4:10am?

I just want to know so I can decide whether to stay at Int airport or go to the domestic one at night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the Mumbai International airport website, the airport transfer service runs non-stop 24h:](http://www.csia.in/passenger/inter-terminal-transfers.aspx)

[image: BOM airport transfer]

For tips and tricks on where to sleep in the airport, see our other question on the topic: [Where to spend a night in the Mumbai airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18940/where-to-spend-a-night-in-the-mumbai-airport?rq=1)

Comment: Great information.. It helped me a lot

Comment: As of 2017, this service is possibly no longer operating. Please see [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84024/how-to-transfer-between-international-t2-to-domestic-1b-terminals-in-mumbai) for information about pre-paid cabs plying between terminals