# How to transfer between International T2 to Domestic 1B terminals in Mumbai?

Tags: transportation, bom

I will be arriving in Mumbai Terminal T2 on a Turkish Airlines international flight. I have a separately-purchased IndiGo ticket 5 hours later from Terminal 1B (Domestic). In the past I heard of a free bus to transfer.

Is that still the case and if not how do I get to Terminal 1B from Terminal 2?

Answer (score 3):

The [official site](http://www.csia.in/tofrom/In-terminal-transfer.aspx) has:

> Inter-terminal transport facility is available on arrival, at
>   Chhatrapati Shivaji International Airport. It is a dedicated paid
>   Inter Terminal Taxi service available at T1B and T2, on chargeable
>   basis.
>
> There are 2 options of cars with fixed rate as follows:
>
> T1B to T2
>   Sedan – Rs. 245
>   SUV – Rs. 750
>
> T2 to T1B
>   Sedan – Rs. 230
>   SUV – Rs. 750
>
> The counters are located at T1B - Inter-Terminal counter at Arrivals,
>   next to Coffee & more. T2 – Level 2 International Arrival beside the
>   Prepaid Taxi counter, next to Makemytrip counter.
>
> Contact details:
>   T2 Inter-Terminal Counter - (022) 65882672
>   T1B Inter-Terminal Counter - 8767350021

There did used to be a free bus service, but it seems no longer.